# Hide duplicate row ssrs 2005

Tags: reporting-services

I need help trying to hide a row in ssrs 2005
ive tried select distinct and putting an

```
=iif(Previous(Fields!food.Value) = Fields!food.Value,Nothing,Fields!food.Value)
```

my table is a lot bigger than this but just an example

```
Food dish           type    Damaged
Italian soup        A       4
Pizza Supreme       B       13
Pizza Supreme       B       12
Spaghetti           C       10
```

and I want Pizza supreme line 2 to be hidden
Thanks

Comment: where are you typing this expression?

Comment: i was placing it in the wrong place i thought it went in the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide rows you need to set the Row Visibility based on an expression using `Previous`.

With your data:

[image]

I have a simple table:

[image]

I have set the Row Visibility to be expression based:

[image]

```
=IIf(Previous(Fields!food.Value) = Fields!food.Value, true, false)
```

This hides the row as required:

[image]